# MediaPlayer getTrackInfo() never include TimedText

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I tried this sample project by iTech (can be found [here](https://github.com/iTech-Developer/TimedTextTest))
Its about displaying subtitle with Android MediaPlayer class.

When I try running the project, media player works okay but the subtitle doesn't. After debugging I've found out that getTrackInfo() only returns an array with length of 2 (that is only the video and audio track) and the timedText track wasnt included in the array. Anyone know why?

For convenience purpose, I post the snippet of the code below:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);
        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.video);

        try {
            player.addTimedTextSource(getSubtitleFile(R.raw.sub),
                    MediaPlayer.MEDIA_MIMETYPE_TEXT_SUBRIP);
            int textTrackIndex = findTrackIndexFor(
                    TrackInfo.MEDIA_TRACK_TYPE_TIMEDTEXT, player.getTrackInfo());
            Log.d(TAG, "textTrackIndex = "+textTrackIndex);
            if (textTrackIndex >= 0) {
                player.selectTrack(textTrackIndex);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Cannot find text track!");
            }
            player.setOnTimedTextListener(this);
            player.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private int findTrackIndexFor(int mediaTrackType, TrackInfo[] trackInfo) {
        int index = -1;
        Log.w(TAG, "trackinfo length = "+trackInfo.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < trackInfo.length; i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "track type = "+trackInfo[i].getTrackType()+" and mediaTrackType = "+mediaTrackType);
            if (trackInfo[i].getTrackType() == mediaTrackType) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
```

Note that if you try the sample project, the video won't be shown but there's only sound. This isn't a bug, since I think iTech purposely doesn't show the video :)

### EDIT:

I've tried on Nexus 10 with Android 4.2.2 it works okay. But still why can't figure out why on my other tablet with Android 4.1.2 it doesn't work...